# Upload local path image from google app script with CSS

Tags: css, image, google-apps-script

Working on google app script, have an style sheet where same code that shows me an image from a web site doesn't work if i want to upload other image from local path, any idea?

```
.calendario{    
background-image: url("C:\Users\FAMILIA\Desktop\Fecha-relev.jpg");
background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

}

Comment: It would probably work in html page such as a web app, a dialog or a sidebar.

Comment: I add from google drive as <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1y1UsMIS9Z-W_6Mu3eoAdGD3Qpeqv">   but would need to link it to a cell in a google sheet, in the way i can paste the link, other case i have to edit avery moth the google app script, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can't actually host your images directly from google drive but you can convert them to a dataUri and load them as follows.

Code.gs

```
function convMediaToDataUri(filename){
  var defaultImage=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-7","yyyyMM") + "MonthlyImage";//I changed the name of the default image a little.  If you have an extension then you need to add that also.
  var filename=filename || defaultImage;
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1d7AcmlPU73AsYRLmxorjBlIdmFYj7DRP");
  var files=folder.getFilesByName(filename);
  var n=0;
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    n++;
  }
  if(n==1) {
    var blob=file.getBlob();
    var b64DataUri='data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
    Logger.log(b64DataUri)
    var fObj={filename:file.getName(),uri:b64DataUri}
    return fObj;
  }
  return null;
}

function showmyImageDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq4');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "My Image")
}
```

html: (in my example I have this in a file named aq4.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>  
<body>
  <img id="img1" />
<script> 
  window.onload=function() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(fObj){
    document.getElementById('img1').src= fObj.uri;
    })
    .convMediaToDataUri();
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thank you, but can't make it work. I have added the folder ID on var folder,also change "default image name" for the name,first the name the file had and after i tried changing the name of the file for "img1" and the html  .convMediaToDataUri('imagefilename'); i also added the name and after tried with "img1"....i didn't write the jpg extension. What i'm doing wrong? And what i interprete is that in this way i can change the image file in the folder every month witjout having to obtein its new  ID, isn't it?

Comment: As with the image ID i can easily load the image, but my problem is that the image change every month, so may be in the way you teach is one way if i figure out how to make it work, or other case i thought to link from the html code to one cell in the spreadsheet and change everymonth the ID there without having to edit the app code...but  i know how to do it in vba but can't figure out how to do it from html addding an script

Comment: Yes, but if i change the image the ID change, and for the moment the only way works for me is to call from the html code  the id  ex: <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=her id number     I still couldn't run the code you show me

Comment: So I changed it so that the converter figures out what the image name is.

Comment: The image id can be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: In my code, the `src` becomes a dataUri which actually contains the entire image.  Fortunately most modern browsers support it.

Comment: Hi Cooper still can't make it work. I detail what i did:

Comment: I copied the peace of code as you wrote...i only change 2 lines, not change complet with id, in this way:  var defaultImage=Utitilites.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-7","yyyyMM") + "globo.jpg";

Comment: var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1Xo3J4UgB9IY6GjuyAvJFH_018qqMhbp7");

Comment: And  add on my dashboard html at the end and after at the star , the script for the html....what do you think i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try it again. I spelled `Utilities` incorrectly.  I just got through testing this and it works in my dialog.